# IE10 HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, internet-explorer-10

Has anyone been experiencing issues with HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection working correctly on IE10?  For some reason this keeps returning false even when I'm on a page in SSL.

Comment: im not sure if it fix your problem but try it and tell me. Add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" > after of the tag <head runat="server">

Comment: I've tried IE=9 and IE=edge and neither work.  The issue is intermittent and occurs on everyone's machine that I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

I think we were able to resolve the issue.  Apparently .NET has a hard time detecting IE10 so we had to apply a hotfix.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: I lied this did not fix the issue.